# How do I scroll using hotkeys?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to recreate this from sublime text:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": -1.0 } },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll by one line is not currently supported by API, but you can use this plugin which implements it:

https://github.com/callum-ramage/ctrl-dir-scroll

Comment: [Here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/can-not-scroll-editor-view-using-keyboard/9676/) the discussion.
Maybe useful built-in shortcut: Ctrl+<, run `editor:scroll-to-cursor` command. Alternative to [ctrl-dir-scroll](https://github.com/callum-ramage/ctrl-dir-scroll) you have [keyboard-scroll](https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-scroll).